# Find correct CMUS alsa device configuration for volume control

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, alsa, music-player

I have a raspberry pi with an IQAudio DAC+ hat installed, running the Volumio linux distribution.

The card works well. I've set the `dsp.alsa.device` setting to `device:1` and this outputs the audio correctly over the DAC hat.

But the CMUS volume control doesn't work.

I think I have to set `mixer.alsa.channel` and `mixer.alsa.device` in CMUS. Right now, they are set to

```
mixer.alsa.channel     PCM
mixer.alsa.device      default
```

What device name and channel name do I use?

I've tried these combinations:

```
mixer.alsa.channel     PCM
mixer.alsa.device      default:1

mixer.alsa.channel     Digital
mixer.alsa.device      default:1

mixer.alsa.channel     PCM
mixer.alsa.device      IQAudioIODac

mixer.alsa.channel     Digital
mixer.alsa.device      IQAudioIODac

mixer.alsa.channel     PCM
mixer.alsa.device      default:CARD=IQaudIODAC

mixer.alsa.channel     Digital
mixer.alsa.device      default:CARD=IQaudIODAC
```

But CMUS always gives the error message `Error: can't change volume: mixer is not open`.

Should I use a different CMUS setting?

Here's my output from `aplay -l`:

```
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 6/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: IQaudIODAC [IQaudIODAC], device 0: IQaudIO DAC HiFi pcm512x-hifi-0 []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

And here's my output from `aplay -L`:

```
hw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
hw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=0
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 ALSA
    Hardware device with all software conversions
plughw:CARD=ALSA,DEV=1
    bcm2835 ALSA, bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI
    Hardware device with all software conversions
default:CARD=IQaudIODAC
    IQaudIODAC, 
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=IQaudIODAC
    IQaudIODAC, 
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=IQaudIODAC,DEV=0
    IQaudIODAC, 
    Direct sample mixing device
dsnoop:CARD=IQaudIODAC,DEV=0
    IQaudIODAC, 
    Direct sample snooping device
hw:CARD=IQaudIODAC,DEV=0
    IQaudIODAC, 
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=IQaudIODAC,DEV=0
    IQaudIODAC, 
    Hardware device with all software conversions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `softvol=true` in CMUS settings panel.

My guess is that CMUS now just adjusts the volume of it's own output, instead of trying to change the volume externally. So, no longer needed to find the correct mixer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I got it working is that I used set `mixer.alsa.device=hw:1`

If you type in `alsamixer`, hit <kbd>F6</kbd> and choose your sound card, and then <kbd>F6</kbd> again "enter your device name", it should show up the right mixer setting name.

Comment: Hello. Could you tell whether the setting is `mixer.alsa.device=hw:1` or `set mixer.alsa.device=hw:1`? You can [edit your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/619553/edit) and format your inline code with a backtick "`"  before and after the code to separate it from other text. It will render as the code in this comment. Where do you put that setting?

Answer (score 1):

for my usb audio dongle on rpi3, these settings worked:

```
set dsp.alsa.device=hw:1

set mixer.alsa.channel=hw:1

set mixer.alsa.device=USB Mixer

set output_plugin=alsa
```

FYI, I got the mixer device name from the cmd `alsamixer info`